# Is it possible to align different lines according to a "waterfall" scheme

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, amsmath

Let's say I have multiple lines of math symbols from which I want to create a kind of "waterfall aligning, i.e. At any given line, the proceeding line will start at the (horizontal) position of end of the current line.

I have attempted to do it with the align environment (using & and &&) but it does not work

```
\begin{align}
F: \mathcal{A} \to & \mathcal{B} \\
 & f: && C \to D\\
&& c \mapsto f(c):= \sum ...
\end{align}
```

Any ideas on how I can do this properly?

Comment: Like the main diagonal of a matrix? Then `matrix` environment, or more generally the `array` env, is an option.

Comment: I don't think one can do that properly (in the sense that, I cannot see an example where this is a good solution). I might be wrong, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `alignat`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
F\colon \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B} \\
& f\colon  C \to D \\
&& c \mapsto f(c) = \sum ...
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]